# Resize image in java without using ImageIO

Tags: java, image, resize, javax.imageio

We have successfully resized the images by getting the JPEG thumbnail data, but there are certain images that doesn't have one.

The solution is just to resize the image to be able to create a thumbnail, but can only use Java 1.4 and below (hence I can't use ImageIO because the device doesn't support it)

Is there any solution to my problem on how to resize an image using ImageIO?

Comment: You can retrieve a resized instance of a `java.awt.Image` with `Image.getScaledInstance`.

Comment: Why does Java 1.4 lead to `OutOfMemoryException`?

Comment: @haraldK because the device that we're using it for doesn't have that much memory.

Comment: Okay.. Then update the question. State what kind of device it is, and what kind of Java (as it is not the full Java 2 SE 1.4) it does support. Maybe also state the amount of memory it has. This will give people who want to help you a chance to do so. :-)

Comment: I updated the question sir. hmmm I can't state the specific device that we're working on. @haraldK

Answer (score 0):

`java.awt.Image.getScaledInstance(width, height, hints)` returns a new, scaled instance of the Image.

The last parameter `hints` changes the scaling methods used, which will modify the resulting appearence. See the snippet below, taken directly from the JDK source.

```
 /**
 * Use the default image-scaling algorithm.
 * @since JDK1.1
 */
public static final int SCALE_DEFAULT = 1;

/**
 * Choose an image-scaling algorithm that gives higher priority
 * to scaling speed than smoothness of the scaled image.
 * @since JDK1.1
 */
public static final int SCALE_FAST = 2;

/**
 * Choose an image-scaling algorithm that gives higher priority
 * to image smoothness than scaling speed.
 * @since JDK1.1
 */
public static final int SCALE_SMOOTH = 4;

/**
 * Use the image scaling algorithm embodied in the
 * <code>ReplicateScaleFilter</code> class.
 * The <code>Image</code> object is free to substitute a different filter
 * that performs the same algorithm yet integrates more efficiently
 * into the imaging infrastructure supplied by the toolkit.
 * @see        java.awt.image.ReplicateScaleFilter
 * @since      JDK1.1
 */
public static final int SCALE_REPLICATE = 8;

/**
 * Use the Area Averaging image scaling algorithm.  The
 * image object is free to substitute a different filter that
 * performs the same algorithm yet integrates more efficiently
 * into the image infrastructure supplied by the toolkit.
 * @see java.awt.image.AreaAveragingScaleFilter
 * @since JDK1.1
 */
public static final int SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING = 16;
```

Comment: Based on my research, I have to use imageIO for the BufferedImage. Is there any other way that I won't be able to use ImageIO for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try This code, Just put the size you want for Width and height and it will give you required image. Its shortest code I have found till now. works fine for me.

```
    Bitmap yourBitmap;
    Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```